# ReactJS Workflow in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, requirejs, reactjs, webstorm

Huge fan on Intellij for Java(love it and love shortcuts).

Trying to get my head around using WebStrom for ReactJS.

- Is there any additional tuning that can be done ?
- How to quickly create new react class without copy/paste, what is the short cut ?
- How to navigate around classes quickly ?
- How to use imports with ease e.g. require that with quick understanding of my project structure while I type ?
- How to build gulp from Webstorm ?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- set `Javascript language version` to `'JSX harmony`' in `Settings/Languages&Frameworks/JavaScript`, make sure that react.js is available in your project (or configured as a library)
- I can suggest creating the corresponding live template (`Settings/Editor/Live Templates`)
- Navigate/Symbol
- no auto-imports functionality provided. The only help you can get is paths completion
- see http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/11/gulp-in-webstorm-9/

Comment: thank you for your answer, just and additional question, is it possible to add custom shortcuts like sout tab in intellij in Webstorm how is this functionality called ?

Comment: not sure what 'custom shortcuts' you refer to - can you explain?

Comment: type word 'sout' in Intellij(Java) and press tab, how to create these custom goodies ?

Comment: ah, I see:) it is about live templates. Sure they are supported in WebStorm - Settings/Editor/Live Templates

Comment: awesome, sorted this out. спасибо !

Comment: So there is no way to have auto completion for named export for react module in lines like `import React, {Prototype, Component} from 'react';` ?

Comment: why not? When you hit Ctrl+space inside { }, WebStorm suggests named exports from the module specified in 'from'

Answer (score 2):

1. Do try [jetbrains-react](https://github.com/minwe/jetbrains-react) live templates. They are really useful.
2. To get enhance code completion with typed parameter information, add a TypeScript definition file.
   Go to *Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries*, click *Download*…, search for `react` and click *Download and Install*. You can also download all associated react libraries like `redux`, `react-redux` etc
3. Check all the `React` coding assistance provided by WebStorm in [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/10/working-with-reactjs-in-webstorm-coding-assistance/) blog post.

Also make sure to use the latest [Webstorm 2016.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/) as it provides enhanced support for React.