# React/JSX support in WebStorm?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, jsx

I cannot get JSX support in WebStorm. That is, it does not recognise JSX in react component render methods. It just looks like this to me :

[image]

Apparently it is possible, and there is some documentation on the web :

https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/10/working-with-reactjs-in-webstorm-coding-assistance/

It states that you should use JSX Harmony which can be found in **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript**.

But in my version of WebStorm (i.e. the latest 2016.3) there is no such checkbox for JSX Harmony. There is something called JSX Emmet which is already checked by default... but does not help.

Comment: check this one might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798593/reactjs-workflow-in-webstorm

Answer (score 16):

I just realised that there is a Javascript language version drop down which you have to change to React JSX. It wasn't clear to me in the documentation, or the 'search' field in the Settings window.

Basically you have to do the following :

[image]

And you are done :)

Comment: The picture is missing, please also provide text directions

Comment: @JamieHutber How did you fix it it? I have the same issue

Comment: I think I did `invalidate cache and restart phpstorm`? Give that a whirl

Comment: if anyone has similar problem ... In my case I had main project .idea folder and nested folder with another .idea folder. Only after removing nested .idea I was able to change language to JSX.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to create `.jsx` files, but in the next session WebStorm didn't recognize it anymore. `Override File Type` did solve the issue for me.

[image: File menu]
[image: Override file type]

Another option is to create a file without an extension and use the automatic dialog to associate the type:
[image: File type association]

Answer (score 0):

Please open "Editor | File Types > React JSX"  and check-in "File name patterns" for "React JSX". If `*.jsx` is not there then please add.
[image]